# Condense multiple columns into single column based on which has a value

Tags: r, tidyverse

I'm trying to condense some data in multiple into a single column based on which column has a certain value. Here is an example of how I did it manually. I now need to do this for a much larger group of columns. Is there a way to do this more intelligently? I'd prefer a tidyverse answer if possible.

```
data <- structure(list(
  `Race: (choice=Asian)` = c("Unchecked", "Unchecked", 
    "Unchecked", "Unchecked", "Unchecked", "Unchecked"),
  `Race: (choice=Black)` = c("Unchecked", 
    "Unchecked", "Unchecked", "Unchecked", "Checked", "Checked"), 
  `Race: (choice=White)` = c("Checked", "Checked", "Checked", 
    "Unchecked", "Unchecked", "Unchecked"),
  `Race: (choice=Other)` = c("Unchecked", 
    "Unchecked", "Unchecked", "Checked", "Unchecked", "Unchecked"
), ID = 1:6), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

data$race=NA_character_
data[data$`Race: (choice=Other)`=="Checked",]$race="Other"
data[data$`Race: (choice=White)`=="Checked",]$race="White"
data[data$`Race: (choice=Black)`=="Checked",]$race="Black"
data[data$`Race: (choice=Asian)`=="Checked",]$race="Asian"
```

As you see above, I want the new column to have the value of the column name which is checked. I understand there might be an issue if more than one is checked. I can handle that before I run this but it would be even better if there were a "multiple checked" option as well.

I was able to do this using group_by and cur_group_id but it still doesn't entirely solve the problem.

```
data %>% group_by(across(contains("Race:"))) %>%
  mutate(Race = cur_group_id() %>%
           recode("1" = "Black", "2" = "White", "3" = "Other",
                  "4" = "Asian", "5" = NA_character_))
```

The trouble with this is it requires I manually determine the column id match to the column name. I'm also concerned it may not be robust to changes in the order of the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this `tidyverse` approach reshaping your data and then joining:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Code
datan <- data %>% left_join(
  data %>% pivot_longer(-ID) %>%
    mutate(var=gsub(')','',ifelse(value=='Checked',sub('.*=', '', name),NA))) %>%
    filter(!is.na(var)) %>% select(ID,var))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 6
  `Race: (choice=Asia~ `Race: (choice=Blac~ `Race: (choice=Whit~ `Race: (choice=Oth~    ID var  
  <chr>                <chr>                <chr>                <chr>               <int> <chr>
1 Unchecked            Unchecked            Checked              Unchecked               1 White
2 Unchecked            Unchecked            Checked              Unchecked               2 White
3 Unchecked            Unchecked            Checked              Unchecked               3 White
4 Unchecked            Unchecked            Unchecked            Checked                 4 Other
5 Unchecked            Checked              Unchecked            Unchecked               5 Black
6 Unchecked            Checked              Unchecked            Unchecked               6 Black
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `max.col` to get the first occurrence of `'Checked'` in each row.

```
cols <- grep('Race', names(data), value = TRUE)
values <- cols[max.col(data[cols] == 'Checked', ties.method = 'first')]
values
#[1] "Race: (choice=White)" "Race: (choice=White)" "Race: (choice=White)"
#[4] "Race: (choice=Other)" "Race: (choice=Black)" "Race: (choice=Black)"
```

Maybe clear the column names :

```
values <- gsub('.*choice=|\\)$', '', values)
values
#[1] "White" "White" "White" "Other" "Black" "Black"
```

Comment: This is also a great answer; thank you for showing another way to do it. Ultimately, I went with the tidyverse answer because it works better with my workflow.